# retrieving related field in controller index function gives error but ok in show function

Tags: laravel, relational-database

I define the relation in Company table (where I added the plural):

```
protected $table = 'companies';

public function country() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, "country_id")->withDefault(['country' => 'unknown']);
}
```

I also did the same in the Country model.

When I use the following code in the controller show function it works:

```
public function show (Company $company) {
    $company->country = $company->country()->pluck('country');
```

But if I use the same code in the index function in a loop, I get an error "Call to undefined method stdClass::country()":

```
public function index (Company $company) {
    if (request('tag')) {
        $companies = Tag::where('name',request('tag'))->firstOrFail()->companies;
        $companies->page_title = "Businesses matching tag '".request('tag')."'";
    } else {
        $companies = DB::table('companies')
           ->where([['is_active', '=', '1']])
           ->orderBy('company')
           ->get();
    }
    foreach($companies as $key => $thisCompany) {
        ...
        $thisCompany->country = $company->country()->pluck('country');
    }
```

I guess it is due to the fact that $company is created in the loop and not passed through the function like in show(Company $company)... but I could not find how to solve this issue... so help will be appreciated.

I have added the model in the argument of the function and change the name of the $company variable in the loop by $thisCompany to avoid confusion with the $company model.

No error but the field $country->country does not contain the name of the country but "Illuminate\Support\Collection {#443 …1}"

Why is it so complicated?  Please help...

Comment: Show us how you are doing the query in the index function. Maybe you are using DB Query Builder instead Eloquent.

Comment: Thank you @porloscerrosΨ I have updated my original post.

Comment: What about if you change `DB::table('companies')` by `Company`? Take in mind that the `country` relationship is defined in your Company model, and DB Query Builder ( Ie: `DB::table('companies')` ) doesn't know about relationships.

Comment: I understand the idea @porloscerrosΨ but that gives an error : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fairtrade.company' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `company` where (`is_active` = 1) order by `company` asc)

Comment: I'm guessing Laravel can't determine the plural form of the word "Company". That's weird because on the controller `show` function it works. You can try manually specify the model's table name by defining a table property on the Company model  `protected $table = 'companies';`  as stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ thank you again... but the problem is not solved yet.  With your suggestion and some modification, I do not get an error but the country variable is not getting the associated country name... please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul, sorry, I think I didn't explain myself well in the comments.

What I meant by "What about if you change `DB::table('companies')` by `Company`?", is to stop using DB Query Builder to use the Eloquent `Company` model.

Specifically in this segment of code:

```
$companies = DB::table('companies')
    ->where([['is_active', '=', '1']])
    ->orderBy('company')
    ->get();
```

So, it could be:

```
$companies = Company::where([['is_active', '=', '1']])
    ->orderBy('company')
    ->get();
```

The explanation is that in the first way (with [DB Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#running-database-queries)), the query will return a collection of generic objects (the PHP `stdClass` object) that do not know anything about the `Company` and its relationships.

On the other hand, if you use the [Eloquent model](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#introduction) `Company`, it will return a collection of `Company` objects, which do know about [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction), and specifically the relationship that you have defined as `country`.

Then, when you loop over the collection, you will be able to access the `country` relation of each `Company` object:

```
foreach($companies as $key => $company) {
    //...
    $company->country = $company->country()->pluck('country');
}
```

Finally, your code could looks like:

```
public function index () {
    if (request('tag')) {
        $companies = Tag::where('name',request('tag'))->firstOrFail()->companies;
        $companies->page_title = "Businesses matching tag '".request('tag')."'";
    } else {
        $companies = Company::where([['is_active', '=', '1']])
           ->orderBy('company')
           ->get();
    }
    foreach($companies as $key => $company) {
        //...
        $company->country = $company->country()->pluck('country');
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: In the meantime, I found a way around which was redifining the relationship with a join in the query.  Your solution is much better!  Thank you @porloscerros for taking the time to explain in details.

Comment: Will your solution also work when a tag is passed through the controller?  @porloscerrosΨ, I mean will the $company->country()->pluck('country'); be ok as the $companies are defined as Tag::where('name',request('tag'))->firstOrFail()->companies; ?

Comment: This `$companies = Tag::where('name',request('tag'))->firstOrFail()->companies;` should work (if you have the `companies` relationship defined in the `Tag` model). What I'm not sure is the part that you do `$companies->page_title = "Businesses matching tag '".request('tag')."'";`, it would have to be tested, but I think it would be better to return it separately from the collection of companies